# Authentication between multiple web applications

Tags: php, web-applications, authentication

I am planning on creating a number of web applications that allows the user to share an account between these applications. I am using apache, php and mysql.

My question is, is it possible for the user to login on one server and then be able to use all the applications with these login details. I was thinking of using some kind of web service/api that can be accessed by the other applications but I am not entirely sure that this is the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to go for the popular [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID):

> OpenID is an open standard that
>   describes how users can be
>   authenticated in a decentralized
>   manner, obviating the need for
>   services to provide their own ad hoc
>   systems and allowing users to
>   consolidate their digital identities.

There is also [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication system:

> OAuth (Open Authorization) is an open
>   standard for authorization. It allows
>   users to share their private resources
>   (e.g. photos, videos, contact lists)
>   stored on one site with another site
>   without having to hand out their
>   credentials, typically username and
>   password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I have heard alot of bad things about OpenID recently due to problems with service providers. Oauth on the other hand might be an idea so I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I would build an authentication service. Then I would register within that service which applications the user can use.